# sending div to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

i would like to send a div to another page actually im using javascript it work but i dont think its effecient cause it just show it it dont really send it, is there another way with ajax or jquery //my script send div:envoi to contenu.php under div:recu

```
function popWindow()
{
    var pop = window.open('contenu.php'); self.focus();
    if(pop.focus){ pop.focus(); }
}


function showIt() {
               var cont = self.opener.document.getElementById('Envoi').innerHTML;
               document.getElementById('recu').innerHTML = cont;
                }
```

Comment: "it just show it it dont really send it" <-- what the hell does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, that should work, assuming the showIt function is called within the popup window, within the onload event of the page body (or at some point after the 'recu' element have been drawn).

Comment: as i said it work but  it only show the div it dont really send it dynamcly

Comment: @user653836: There is no such thing as "sending" a div "dynamically", other than what you are already doing. Why do you think that it's not right now?

Comment: @ Tomalak Geret'kal: is there a way using XMLHttpRequestObject ??or $.post in jquery?thats what i'm searching for

Comment: in my example if i dont open contenu.php in other window it will not work cause my div(:envoi)will be lost so a way is to put div:envoi in a variable